# Equation of the Tangent Plane to the Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface 
$$
z= \exp\Big(\frac{3x}{17}\Big)\ln(4y)
$$ at the point $(4,1,2.808)$. I got 
$$
0.4955512784x+0.506408305y+0.319386581,
$$
but this is apparently incorrect, please help.

Comment: See [tangent plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentPlane.html).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{\vec{r}_{0} \equiv \pars{4,1,2.808}\ \mbox{and}\ \fermi\pars{x,y,z}\equiv\expo{3x/17}\ln\pars{4y} - z}$.

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> \left.\nabla\fermi\pars{x,y,z}\right\vert_{\,\vec{r}\ =\ \vec{r}_{0}}
> &=\pars{{3 \over 17}\,\expo{3x/17}\ln\pars{4y},{\expo{3x/17} \over y},-1}_{\vec{r}\ =\ \vec{r}_{0}}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{0.495551,2.02563,-1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\pars{0.495551,2.02563,-1}\cdot\pars{\vec{r} - \vec{r}_{0}}=0
\\[5mm]&\imp\quad
\color{#66f}{\large 0.495551 x + 2.02563 y - z=1.19984}
\end{align}